# Powershell - Copy Member Of permissions - Filter based on OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to automate copying of permissions from one user to another, which works fine.
Now i want to to not copy any memberships that are in a particular OU

For example, exclude

- domainroot->trial

  - and all sub folders

But keeps all others in domain root, for example

- domainroot

  - folder 1

    - sub folder 1
  - folder 2

    - sub folder 1

I want to filter based on the trial folder, so it and any sub folders don't get included

Currently i use

```
$CopyFromUser = Get-ADUser USERNAME -prop MemberOf
$CopyToUser = Get-ADUser USERNAME -prop MemberOf
$CopyFromUser.MemberOf | Where{$CopyToUser.MemberOf -notcontains $_} |  Add-ADGroupMember -Member $CopyToUser
```

Comment: You say you want to copy "permissions" (ACEs?), but the sample script you show copies group memberships? Which one is it? :)

Comment: So you just want the domain root and want to exclude the trial/other folders containers?

Comment: We have domainroot -> trial, domainroot->folder 1, domainroot->folder 2, etc. We want to exclude all in domainroot->trial only, other ones are fine

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, you can use the `Comparison` operators again such as, `-notmatch`, and `-notcontains`. You have to evaluate them against the *DistinguishedName* property/attribute. `Get-ADUser -Filter $myfilter -Properties $properties -SearchBase $domainDN |  Where-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -notmatch "OU=DomainRoot,OU=Trial"}`

Comment: Get the objectGUID, SID or DN of the OU you wanna exclude and then use `-ne` to exclude said OU? I think you need to be more specific / give more details on what you need.

Comment: Added full code